# vaadin7 with two HorizontalLayout one on the right

Tags: vaadin7

I have `HorizontalLayout` and in it combo `c1` and `c2`:

```
    HorizontalLayout hrzLy1 = new HorizontalLayout();
    mainVertical.addComponent(hrzLy1);
    hrzLy1.setWidth("100%");

    ComboBox c1 = new ComboBox("combo1");
    hrzLy1.addComponent(c1);
    c1.setWidth("100%");

    ComboBox c2 = new ComboBox("combo2");
    hrzLy1.addComponent(c2);
    c2.setWidth("40px");
```

I would like `c2` to be on the right and have just `40px` width.
`c1` should occupy all the left side of the window.
I have try with `setComponentAlignment` but can not get `c1` widther and `setExpandRatio` but when I maximize window, the `c2` is not completely on the right, looks like ratio should be changed in case of the window size change, so I guess ratio is not a solution. I have try with `GridLayout` but I can not set first cell on `100%` and second `40px`. Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want can be achieved by using expand ratio and a full sized c1 - giving expand ratio 1 to the full sized combobox. (but I think I don't fully get what the problem was when you tried it).

Here is what I tried which seems to work like what you want to achieve:

```
HorizontalLayout hrzLy1 = new HorizontalLayout();
hrzLy1.setWidth("100%");

ComboBox c1 = new ComboBox("combo1");
c1.setSizeFull();

ComboBox c2 = new ComboBox("combo2");
c2.setWidth("40px");

hrzLy1.addComponents(c1,c2);
hrzLy1.setExpandRatio(c1, 1.0f);
```

Tested within Vaadin 7.7.13 and a full sized vertical layout as UI content.

[image]